# How to add an action to notifications in Swift 2 iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2

I'm trying to get a button in my notifications send with PHP Apns
http://immobiliare.github.io/ApnsPHP/html/

Following this documentation from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH18-SW5

But the buttons never show..

My code:

```
    var categories = NSMutableSet()

    var acceptAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    acceptAction.title = NSLocalizedString("Accept", comment: "Accept")
    acceptAction.identifier = "accept"
    acceptAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    acceptAction.authenticationRequired = false

    var declineAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    declineAction.title = NSLocalizedString("Decline", comment: "Decline")
    declineAction.identifier = "decline"
    declineAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    declineAction.authenticationRequired = false

    var inviteCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    inviteCategory.setActions([acceptAction, declineAction],
        forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
    inviteCategory.identifier = "cat1"

    categories.addObject(inviteCategory)


    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: (NSSet(array: [categories])) as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

My APNS code:

```
$push = new ApnsPHP_Push(ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION, 'dict_prod.pem');

$push->setProviderCertificatePassphrase('XXXXXXX');
$push->setRootCertificationAuthority('entrust_root_certification_authority.pem');
$push->connect();
$message = new ApnsPHP_Message("THE TOKEN");
$message->setText("Test");
$message->setSound('default');
$message->setExpiry(30);
$message->setCategory('cat1');
$push->add($message);
$push->send();
$push->disconnect();

$aErrorQueue = $push->getErrors();
if (!empty($aErrorQueue)) {
        var_dump($aErrorQueue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be fixed when using:

```
let categories = NSSet(object: inviteCategory)

let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: categories as! Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)
```

Removing:

```
var categories = NSMutableSet()
```

and

```
categories.addObject(inviteCategory)
```